# Python replace character without replace method

Tags: python

I am trying to run the following script with Python:

```
test_string = "Hallo"

test_string[0] = "T"
```

And I am getting the following error:

> 'str' object does not support item assignment

Now I know you can use the replace default function of Python, but is there any other way to achieve the above without using a standard python function ?

thanks,

Comment: you can create a list of letters. but it's weird

Comment: You get the error because strings are immutable. Hence, any solution will just return a new object. However, why do you want to use a non standard function? Is a regex non standard? Are list comprehensions nonstandard? What is bad about replace? Additionally, the question in it's current form is way to broad

Comment: `test_string = list("Hallo")
test_string[0] = 'T'`

Comment: Another non-standard way could be to use a multiclass classifier that classifies the first letter always as T and keeps the remaining letters constant. Then you could predict the class of every letter and concatenate back again. However, this only works for strings of a fixed lenght `n`

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
test_string = "Hallo"
# turn the string into a list
test_string  = list(test_string)
# change the character you want  
test_string[0] = "T"
# convert the list back to a string. 
test_string = "".join(test_string)
```

Comment: @PauloAlmeida exactly, my mistake! Thanks

Comment: Why `test_string = "".join(test_string)`?

Comment: @haccks to get back to a string as the OP wants to change a "string". i.e we change temporary to a list to change a character then we get back to a string.

Comment: `test_string  = list(test_string) ` changes `test_string` in place, i.e. it makes `test_string` list.

Comment: @haccks It makes `test_string` a list, but not "in place". It creates a new list object from the string `test_string` and reassigns the name `test_string` to this new object. I may be missing your point though, are you saying something could be different in this answer or just clarifying?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida; Oh wait! `test_string = list(test_string)` line makes `test_string` a list and a list is mutable object so, why is `test_string = "".join(test_string)`?

Comment: @haccks that's to revert back to a string after modifying the list with `test_string[0] = "T"` as OP wants a string.

Comment: @MedAli; It's not clear if he wants the same but you might be right.

Comment: @haccks it's in the title.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable, so if you don't want to convert to a mutable type, you'll have to create a new string. Here is an example function that does that:

```
def replace_(original_string, replace_string, index):
    return original_string[:index] + replace_string + original_string[index + len(replace_string):]

print(replace_("Hallo", "T", 0))
print(replace_("Hallo", "Te", 0))
```

This outputs:

```
Tallo
Tello
```

I'd like to note that I prefer the answers that convert to a list; this answer is only provided for a pure-string implementation.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to change just the first letter of your string?

You can do

```
t = "T" + t[1:len(t)]
```

note: I've put "t" instead of "test_string"

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension and enumerate like

```
"".join(['T' if i == 0 else x for i, x in enumerate(test_string) ])
```

also works

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using `bytearray` which is a little faster than MedAli's solution:

```
test_string = "Hello"
b = bytearray(test_string)  # Or Python3 bytearray(test_string, 'utf-8')
b[0] = ord('T')
str(b)
```

Comment: This won't work if the string has characters that use more than a byte. Also, in Python 3 you have to specify an encoding, but that won't help with the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that nobody did the obvious...

```
test_string = "T" + test_string[1:]
```

Comment: Someone did, actually, but they unnecessarily added `len(test_string)` to the slice. It is a bit more cumbersome if the character you want to replace isn't in the beginning or end.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Yeah I saw that. It's not the same.